# No progress bar in IE8 while executing the download using PHP

Tags: php, internet-explorer, http, internet-explorer-8

I am giving downloads to user using the PHP code below but when user downloading they are not able to see the progressbar in IE8 when clicked on save button. Please solve this.
Thanks in advance.

```
header('Content-Description: Songsbin.com - Downlaod');
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename1);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, I also tried and both in Chrome and IE8 it works good...

if you succeed to download the file check that `filesize($file)` returns a correct output..

Comment: i checked deleting header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file)); and also added the values but still not showing the progress bar in ie8, downloading is working fine, but why the progress bar is not showing ? 

thanks in advance

Comment: I really don't know, I used your exactly code and the progress bar is shown (with ie8 ofc)...

Answer (score 0):

remove the `'Expires: 0'` header directive

Comment: Can you explain why this changes things?